# x84 gnu linker filled up content in reserved address space

Tags: c, object, assembly, linker

I have an area of reserved address space in the linker script,
{
    . = 1M
    ...
    ...
}

however, when using it to linking x64 object files, ld will produce an extra 1MB in the final executable file, so it seemed that the linker filled up the reserved address space with empty content. but it is fine when link 32 bit cdoes. I am very confused about this. any idea why this problem happened?

Comment: What if you use `-z max-page-size=0x1000` when linking to force page size to 4kb?

Comment: Someone needs to write a [x86-64 Bare Bones](http://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Bare_Bones) tutorial.